# Subsetting multiple dataframes within a list keeping variables ending with CD and RESN in R

Tags: r

I have a list of 3 data frames `A`,`B` and `C` with 3 variables in each named as `(ID,ACD,ARESN),(ID,BCD,BRESN)` and `(ID,CCD,CRESN)` respectively.

How do I subset all three dataframes within this list selecting variables ending with `CD` and `RESN`?

Comment: If last two columns per df, use the extract function: `lapply(df_list,  "[", 2:3)`

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that subsets a single data frame selecting variables ending with CD and RESN, then `lapply(your_list, that_function)`.

```
select_cols_regex = function(x, pattern) {
  x[grepl(pattern, names(x))]
}

lapply(your_list, select_cols_regex, pattern = c("(CD|RESN)$"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. However, when I'm trying to define the function, it is giving me an error like  select_cols_regex = function(x, pattern) { 
+   x[grepl(pattern, names(x)] 
Error: unexpected ']' in:
"select_cols_regex = function(x, pattern) { 
  x[grepl(pattern, names(x)]"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Worked. I missed a ")"